# Only Last Image Store in Array Get Display in Table view

Tags: ios

My code below will produce the correct amount of data in array but the display data will only take the last value and display repeated.
For Example:

When i selected the first image then the first image is successfully display in table view.
When i selected the second image then the array will has 2 data but problem is in table view i will get 2 same image (the second selected image). My expected result will be when selected the second image the first image will still be there and the second display at the subsequence row.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSLog(@"Collector in photoList %@",self.collector);

for (int i = 0; i < collector.count; i++) {
// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);

};

NSLog(@"Collector %@",self.collector);

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:[collector objectAtIndex:i] resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

cell.imageView.image = galleryImage;
NSLog(@"Gallery image is %@",self.galleryImage);
    return cell;
```

}

**EDITED!**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSLog(@"Collector in photoList %@",self.collector);

for (int i = 0; i < collector.count; i++) {
// define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];

        //Added mutable array for galleryImage
        [photoCollector addObject:galleryImage];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
    NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);

};

NSLog(@"Collector %@",self.collector);

// get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:[collector objectAtIndex:i] resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

 //Display image 
if(photoCollector.count != 0)
{
    cell.imageView.image = [self.photoCollector objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

NSLog(@"This is in cellForRowAtIndexPath");
NSLog(@"Gallery image is %@",self.galleryImage);

// Configure the cell...
return cell;
```

}

EDITED code at picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo!!

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// Initialize  View Controller
PhotosListViewController *photoListViewController = [[PhotosListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotosListViewController" bundle:nil];
ImageModel *imgModel = [[ImageModel alloc]init];

// get the ref url
imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

//set the imageUrl to the imageModel url in property ?
imgModel.url = imageURL;

[self.collector addObject:imageURL];
photoListViewController.urlCollector = self.collector;
NSLog(@"Collector in root %@",self.collector);

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoListViewController animated:YES];
```

}

**EDITED FULL CODE!!**

**RootViewController.m**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// Initialize  View Controller
PhotosListViewController *photoListViewController = [[PhotosListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotosListViewController" bundle:nil];

// get the ref url
imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

[self.collector addObject:imageURL];
photoListViewController.urlCollector = self.collector;

NSLog(@"Collector in root %@",self.collector);

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoListViewController animated:YES];


}
```

**ImageModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^handler)(UIImage *image);

@interface ImageModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *imageUrl;

- (void)getImageWithCompletionHandler:(handler)completionBlock;

@end
```

**ImageModel.m**

```
 #import "ImageModel.h"
 #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
 #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

 @implementation ImageModel
 @synthesize imageUrl;

 - (void)getImageWithCompletionHandler:(handler)completionBlock
{
   ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
  {
    ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        completionBlock(image);
    }

};

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:self.imageUrl resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
}
@end
```

**PhotoListViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    test1 = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    self.imageModelObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSURL *url in self.urlCollector)
  {
     ImageModel *imageModel = [[ImageModel alloc] init];
     imageModel.imageUrl = url;
     [self.imageModelObjects addObject:imageModel];
  }
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      }    

ImageModel *model = [self.imageModelObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[model getImageWithCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    });

}];


return cell;
```

}

Comment: GalleryImage is just a UIImage. Everytime u call the assetForURL: method, galleryImage will be replaced. So obvious after the for loops completes your galleryImage will contain the last image. Instead of galleryImage u can use the NSMutableArray and add the images to the array for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: It is work (please see my edited code above) but it is a bit troublesome if user delete the image added in table view because need to remove one by one from different array. Is it got other easy way to maintain the array?

Comment: Its better to consider having a model. I have edited the code below adding a model. Hope it helps :) .

Comment: Hi Norbert, can you interpret more details the model way you suggested or got any reference because i am totally new with this model.I tried search in google but it giving me a lot of non related model to me.

Comment: I have updated the code. U can refer http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-design-patterns-model-view-controller-part-3

Comment: Once you are done reading and understood the example of book model. you can relate book model with u r image model. Like the book model has title and author, your model contains the image url and also it gives u the image whenever u call the method getImage....

Comment: Hi Norbert, many thanks to u ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *images;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Collector in photoList %@",self.collector);

    for (int i = 0; i < collector.count; i++) {
        // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
        {
            ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
            if (iref) {
                [self.images addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref]];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
            NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);

        };

        NSLog(@"Collector %@",self.collector);

        // get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)

        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:[collector objectAtIndex:i] resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.images.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.imageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

## Edited:

## ImageModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^handler)(UIImage *image);

@interface ImageModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *imageURL;

- (void)getImageWithCompletionHandler:(handler)completionBlock;

@end
```

## ImageModel.m

```
#import "ImageModel.h"

@implementation ImageModel

- (void)getImageWithCompletionHandler:(handler)completionBlock
{
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [imageRep fullResolutionImage];
        if (iref) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
            completionBlock(image);
        }

    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:self.imageURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
}
```

## Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ImageModel.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageModelObjects;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageModelObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSURL *url in self.collector)
    {
         ImageModel *imageModel = [[ImageModel alloc] init];
         imageModel.url = url;
         [self.imageModelObjects addObject:imageModel]
     }

      //You can discard the collecter. IF u want the url, u can get from the self.imageModelObjects.
      self.collector = nil;

 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    ImageModel *model = [self.imageModelObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [model getImageWithCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = image;
        });
    }];


    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What i should put in at the comment there:                          - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageModelObjects = //Should contain image model objects.
}

Comment: For my clarification, in viewDidLoad of controller.m is it we pass the url to the imageModel.m to load the image?                for(NSURL *url in self.collector)
    {
         ImageModel *imageModel = [[ImageModel alloc] init];
         imageModel.url = url;
         [self.imageModelObjects addObject:imageModel]
     }

Comment: Question not clear. Our objective is instead of storing the NSURL object in the array, we are storing our own custom object , that is ImageModel. Each ImageModel object should know what url it has and also should return the image for the url.

Comment: i am confusing with the imageUrl used in imageModel.h where declare as property, where the imageUrl get data from? sorry for the slow understanding.

Comment: imageUrl is interface as it in .h file, Means it should set by the object that creates it. In viewDidLoad if u check we are creating ImageModel object by [[ImageModel alloc] init] and in the next line we are setting the url which we get from the collector array. Assuming your collector array has the NSURL objects.

Comment: That mean @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *imageURL is set when selected the image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo (code edited above)? i tried to pass the imageUrl from this method but i cant get any picture display. By the way, for this code imageModel.url = url mean in imageModel it has a variable to store the url?

Comment: I edited full code on above where i still cant manage to display the image selected. I don't know where is going wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Hi Norbert, i already created my github and uploaded the source code. This is the [link](https://github.com/YukikoLim/sickNote).

Comment: Hi @yukiko i have forked your source code and updated it. Check out the the link  https://github.com/NorbertHere/sickNote . Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Nobert, may i know what Xcode version you are using, i not manage to open the PhotoCell.xib.

Comment: Its **Xcode5** latest one. `PhotoCell.xib` contains a `tableview` cell with `imageview` and `textlabel` in it. here is the link which contains the screenshot http://snag.gy/sItp1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
if (iref)
{
    galleryImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];

    //Added mutable array for galleryImage
    [photoCollector addObject:galleryImage];
    [photoCollector retain];


    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
        cell.imageView.image = [self.photoCollector objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```